# Laravel routes not working on production

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, laravel, shared-hosting

I've a Laravel5/angularJS app (beeing Laravel as an api rest and angular for the front-end)

At my local environment everything works like charm.

But when i upload to a hosting i can only access to the index page, everything else throws a 404.

in my shared hosting i have the file-system like this.

```
public_html
    laravel-backend (it has app, bootstrap, confi...etc, all laravel app)
    laravel-frontend (it would be like the public folder of the laravel default file system)
    .htaccess
```

the .htaccess content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} anotherAppDomainAtSharedServer$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} laravelAppDomain$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/laravel-frontend/.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /laravel-frontend/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

index.php inside laravel-frontend:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel-backend/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel-backend/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

and the routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
    ....
```

So, as i said, i can see login page, but when i want to login i get 404 error

```
http://laravelAppDomain/laravel-backend/api/v1/authenticate 404 (Not Found)
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

any clue? any configuration i miss?

In addition, i have not access to configuration server, i mind i can't edit etc folder hosts, vhosts or similar like i did in my local environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how, if someone can give me a theorical answer is welcome.

I changed the folder structure:

```
public_html
    laravel-app
        public
```

the standar laravel way.

then I configure the .htaccess pointing to the public and the request became to work.

Comment: But it's a bad idea to have your full `laravel-app` available within the web-server's publicly-viewable directory structure. See this article as to some suggestions... (https://laravel-news.com/subfolder-install)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're on an apache2 server on Unix:

- run the command `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
- make sure that there's a section of your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` that looks like the following. Note that `/var/www/html` is the root directory default of apache2, yours may be `/var/www/html/public` or something to that effect.

  `<Directory /var/www/html>
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>`
- run `sudo service apache2 restart`
- see if that works.

Comment: i can't see those files, i've only have access to public-html folder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the other steps are necessary to work, but did you try just running the `a2enmod` command and restarting the server to check if that fixed?

Comment: i have not ssh acces, i can only enter through c-panel so i can't run any console command.

Comment: I'm sorry then, not sure how to help you

Comment: thanks anyway, i know what was your point an that's exactly what i did on my local environment, but in this server i'm tied by the hands